# Are there google apis to update a google sheet

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

I want to listen to calendar events and update cells in the google sheet.

I have found apis for calendar but are there any apis available to update cells in google sheet ?
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Thanks

Comment: Try this search: [api update cells in google sheet](https://www.google.com/search?q=api+update+cells+in+google+sheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).
But you are probably better off using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to access Calendar and Sheets.